# cannot update the powershell task version on azure devops pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

​when I am creating a build or a release the PowerShell task only allows me to choose between versions 1* and 2*. I have installed more recent versions of PowerShell on the build agents and I have also added it as a capability on the agents but I still see only versions 1* and 2*. so can you please help me?

Comment: Keep in mind this is Task Version, not PowerShell version. I also have task versions 1* and 2* for PS (also for Azure CLI). Is there something you are unable to do with task version 2*?

Answer (score 0):

That's not the PowerShell version, it's the PowerShell **task** version. Azure DevOps build/release tasks are versioned, and that version is completely unrelated to the version of PowerShell.

To use a different version of PowerShell, just make sure the `PATH` environment variable on the agent is pointing to the correct version of `powershell.exe`. If you want to use PowerShell Core (`pwsh`), set the `pwsh` flag to `true`. Refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops).